# Is it true that if $M$ is injective then $S^{-1}M$ is also injective

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $R$. Is it true that for any injective $R$-module like $M$, $S^{-1}M$ (as the $S^{-1}R$-module) is also injective ?

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140631.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, this is false in general. I quote the Mathematical Review of Dade, Everett C.
*Localization of injective modules*. 
J. Algebra 69 (1981), no. 2, 416–425.

> Localization of modules over a commutative ring *R* with respect to a multiplicatively closed subset *S* of *R* is an exact functor with a large number of properties, some of which are listed in Theorem 3.76 of J. J. Rotman's book [An introduction to homological algebra, Academic Press, New York, 1979; MR0538169 (80k:18001)]. The fifth property, namely: (LI) the localization $S^{−1}E$ of any injective *R*-module *E* is an injective $S^{−1}R$-module, is false. Two examples are given here showing that arbitrary *R* and *S* need not have the property (LI). Also a positive result is given, showing that (LI) holds for certain non-Noetherian *R* and certain *S*. In particular, if *R* is the polynomial ring $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ in a countable number of $x_n$ over a nonzero Noetherian ring *k*, then (LI) holds for all choices of *S*.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any other example ? (other that Everett's paper)

Comment: It says (Everett's paper) the problem is true when $R$ is Noetherian. Do you know a reference ?

Comment: The second edition of Rotman's book gives a correct proof in the noetherian case.

Comment: I have no access to Rotman's book now. But thanks anyway. What about when $M$ is projective ? Does it mean $S^{-1}M$ would be projective ?

Comment: Yes, that's obvious. If *M* is a direct summand of the free module *F*, then $S^{-1}M$ is a direct summand of the free module $S^{-1}F$.

Comment: So in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, in Lemma III.6.1, he says that if $X$ is a ringed space, and $U\subset X$ open, then if $I$ is an injective object of $Mod(X)$, then $I|_U$ is an injective object of $Mod(U)$. I'm confused about how this doesn't contradict your answer here. Doesn't Hartshorne's Lemma 6.1 say that localization of injectives are injective?

Comment: @oxeimon $\mathrm{Spec}\, S^{-1}A$ is not necessarily an open subset of $\mathrm{Spec}\,A$!

Comment: Ah! So the issue is with weird non-finite type localizations... Thanks!

Comment: Even for not-so-weird localizations, you don't get an open subset. E.g. $\mathbb Q$ is a localization of $\mathbb Z$...

Answer (score 13):

When $R$ is noetherian, yes: By Baer's criterion it suffices to prove that the map

$\hom_{S^{-1} R}(S^{-1} R,S^{-1} M) \to \hom_{S^{-1} R}(J,S^{-1} M)$

is surjective for every ideal $J \subseteq S^{-1} R$. Write $J = S^{-1} I$ for some ideal $I \subseteq R$. Since $I$ (and of course $R$) are of finite presentation, this map is isomorphic to

$S^{-1} \hom_R(R,M) \to S^{-1} \hom_R(I,M),$

which is surjective since $\hom_R(R,M) \to \hom_R(I,M)$ is surjective.

The same proof also shows the converse: If $M$ is injective locally (either in the sense that all $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ are injective over $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ runs through all prime ideals, or if there is a basic open cover $\mathrm{Spec}(R) = \cup_i D(f_i)$ such that each $M_{f_i}$ is an injective $R_{f_i}$-module), then $M$ is injective. See also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123559).

You can also see this as a consequence of the fact that the Ext functor, when restricted to f.g. modules over a noetherian ring, commutes with localization.